# Binary Tree template, class specific function call

Tags: templates, binary-tree, function-call

Ok just a heads up, this is my first question on here so i apologize if I don't include every relevant piece of info on my first go, but I'll do my best.

My problem is with a specific function I'm trying to write in main() that will print out data from nodes if their "category" matches the category that is searched for. I'm likely just fumbling with syntax as I'm still pretty new at this. To be clear, the exact problem is that all the function calls I've tried tell me *****"No instance of Overloaded function "BinTree::inOrderTraverse [with Type=CategorizedContact]" matches the argument list. argument types are: (void). Object type is BinTree***** Here's the relevant main() code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept> //invalid_argument
using namespace std;
#include "name.h"
#include "contact.h"
#include "address.h"
#include "BinTree.h"
#include "BinNode.h"
#include "CategorizedContact.h"
#include "Field.h"
#include "htmlfunc.h"
using namespace AddressInfo;
void printMenu();
void printByCat(CategorizedContact&, int);
int getMenuInput();
int validateMenuInput(Field input);
Field printCategoryMenu();
Field categorySelection();

int main()
{

    Address tmpAddress;
    Name tmpName, tmpName2;
    CategorizedContact tmpContact, tmpContact2, itemToRemove;
    BinTree<CategorizedContact> myBook;
    Field tmpString1, categoryIn;
    int menuOption = 0, node = 0, count = 0, categoryMenuOption = 0, categoryInt = 0;


    CategorizedContact& tmp = tmpContact2; // I was just experimenting with trying to initialize         
                                          //a ref variable here, to make the function call work.


    myBook.readFile("address.csv");

    do
    {
        printMenu();
        menuOption = getMenuInput();
        switch (menuOption)
    {
    case 1:

        cout << "\t***** Add Contact *****\n\n";

        categoryIn = categorySelection(); //Prints Category menu and gets input
        tmpContact.setCategory(categoryIn); //Assigns category choice to tmpContact
        cin >> tmpContact;                 //Gets the rest of the contact info
        myBook.addItem(tmpContact);     //Adds contact to address book

        myBook.writeFile("address.csv", '\n'); //Writes new contact to file
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "\n\t***** Count Contacts *****\n";
        count = myBook.getNumUsed();
        cout << "Number of Contacts: " << count;
        cout << endl << endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "\n\t***** Print Contacts By Category *****\n";
        categoryIn = printCategoryMenu(); //Prints category menu and gets choice
        if (categoryIn == "All Contacts") 
            myBook.printAll();
        categoryInt = stoi(categoryIn); // converts to int to match required function parameters

        myBook.inOrderTraverse(printByCat(tmp, categoryInt));
        break;
```

That last line before the ***break;*** is the function call I'm struggling with.
Here's it's declaration:

```
void printByCat(CategorizedContact& tmp, int categoryInt)
{
    int count = 1;
    switch (categoryInt)
    {
    case 65:
        if (tmp.getCategory() == "Business")
            cout << count << ". " << tmp << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Error" << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

It's unfinished, and probably not even designed correctly but I can't tell until i manage to get the function call working.
Lastly here's the relevant code from my inOrderTraverse .h and .tem files pertaining to the problem.

```
#ifndef BINTREE_H
#define BINTREE_H
#include <cstdlib> // NULL
#include <string>
#include <iostream> // cout
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm> // copy
#include "BinNode.h" 
#include "CategorizedContact.h"
#include "Contact.h"
template <class Type>
class BinTree
{
public:
    BinTree();
    BinTree(const BinTree<Type>& source);
    ~BinTree();
    BinTree<Type>& operator=(const BinTree<Type>& source);//assignment operator
    int getNumUsed() const { return(used); }

    void addItem(Type dataIn);

    void printAll();
    void writeFile(string fileName, char delimeter = '\n');
    void readFile(string fileName);
    void inOrderTraverse(void process(Type&, int));
    void debugOn() { debug = true; }
    void debugOff() { debug = false; }

private:
    bool debug;
    int used;
    BinNode<Type>* root;
    void inOrderTraverse(void process(Type&, int),
    BinNode<Type>* cursor, int& count);
    void write(BinNode<Type>* cursor, char delimeter,
    ofstream& outFile);
    void printInOrder(BinNode<Type>* cursor, int& count);
    void free(BinNode<Type>* cursor);
    void copyTree(BinNode<Type>* cursor);
    BinNode<Type>* alloc(Type itemToAdd);
};
#include "BinTree.tem"
```

And just the relevant .tem portions...

```
template <class Type>
void BinTree<Type>::inOrderTraverse(void process(Type&, int))
{
    int count = 1;
    inOrderTraverse(process, root, count);
}
template <class Type>
void BinTree<Type>::inOrderTraverse(void process(Type&, int),
    BinNode<Type>* cursor, int& count)
{
    if (cursor != NULL)
    {
        // In order traverse
        inOrderTraverse(process, cursor->left, count);
        // PROCESS
        process(cursor->data, count);
        count++;
        inOrderTraverse(process, cursor->right, count);
    }
}
```

Before anyone suggests changing the InOrderTraverse(void process(Type&, int)), or the overloaded version, just Know that I'm required to implement it that way for my project.
the only freedom i have is with ***printByCat(CategorizedContact, int)****, that can be changed as long as it's still compatible with inOrderTraverse.
So as i hope u can now see, the function in main() printByCat() is meant to take in a category from the user, and then serve as an argument itself for inOrderTraverse(printByCat()). but I'm obviously making a fundamental mistake that i don't understand.

At this point any guidance would be appreciated, I'm not asking anyone to do the coding for me as i know you are against that, but I really just need to understand why the function call isn't working. I'm guessing the problem stems from my lack of experience with reference variables, but The error I'm getting seems to suggest the function printByCat() which is being taken as an argument of inOrderTraverse, does not meet the argument requirements because it's not a void function, but it is a void function.... so yea I'm a little lost. Anyways thanks for your time, and please let me know if i forgot anything.

Answer (score 0):

Found out what it was, apparently I can't include the arguments of printbyCat() when using this function as an argument of inOrderTraverse(), so the function call should have simply been: myBook.inOrderTraverse(printByCat).